# What are the advantages of using a UISearchBar over a UITextField?

Tags: swift, search, uikit, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am implementing a search feature as part of an app with a custom style Search Bar. As far as I can tell, it seems like somewhat of a pain in the neck to customize the built in UISearchBar. Therefore, I am wondering if anyone can point out the advantages of using a UISearchBar over a UITextField in a UIView which is easily customizable to look the way I'd like? I can't see why I wouldn't be able to filter data on a UITextField `textDidChange` event, in the same way a UISearchBar might. I appreciate any pointers!

Comment: There are some delegate methods unique to `UISearchBar`.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate

Comment: There's no difference. The delegates are a bit different, but just 'different', neither better nor worse.  UISearchBar is infuriating to customize.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not recommend to implement a textfield over a searchController or searchBar, because the last ones provides you with helpful tools to make easier the handling of events in the search, like presentationContext and UISearchResultsUpdating. handling those scopes manually is a pain. I know that customizing options are troublesome for some developers, but is not impossible. Plus: It will be difficult to maintain in the long run.